# Create an executable command in markdown (.md)

Tags: markdown, plantuml

I need to have a link in my markdown file that executes a command whenever It's been clicked which would export an image on a directory.
The command is:

```bash
plantuml -tsvg FILENAME
```

I wrote a PlantUML script in my markdown which that I need to be exported after its linked were clicked.
Whenever I clicked [Here](http://dummy.url) then the command will be executed.

I tried writing the command in the form of:

```bash
plantuml -tsvg activityDiagrams
```

### Edited

The better way to ask is how can I have a trigger in my markdown that execute a command whenever it's been triggered. A dummy example may be a simple button that execute something by pushing it.

Comment: Why not just include the PlantUML in your markdown? There are plug-ins for Pandoc that work very well with PlantUML to produce HTML/PDF. https://github.com/pandoc-ext/diagram#readme